# Unable to display content while using NavigatorIOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigator-ios

I am new to react-native and am building a simple test application.

CODE-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavigatorIOS, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: StartingPage,
          title: 'Test App',
        }}
        style={styles.container}
      />
    );
  }
}

class StartingPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<Text>Some thing to be displayed here</Text>)
  }
}
const styles={
  container:{
    felx:1
  }
}
```

PROBLEM:
[ Application expected to render a component with simple title as 'Test App' which it does and some text which it does not ]

The application renders with a simple title but no text.
Also tried giving following properties to text component with no positive results.

```
textDescription:{
fontSize:18,
textAlign:'center',
color:'#656565',
marginTop:65,
}
```

Any help will be largely appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In react native all Text components need to be within a View component.

Try:

```
return (
  <View>
    <Text>Some thing to be displayed here</Text>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Tried doing that as well still no text.